# Multiple connection in units tests

Tags: unit-testing, symfony

I currently make **units tests** for a **manager** tests suite.

That's work great (no fail) but i have a problem with the **multiple connection**.

After 110 tests launch with phpunit, i have a message to say that ***limit of client exceed***.

I try many ways but i couldn't  resolve this problem.

Have you got a solution for that ???

Comment: Multiple connections to what? A database?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about database connections then at the end of each test you need to explicitly close your connection.  Possibly in the tearDown method.